# Escurecer fundo ao passar o mouse no link

Tags: javascript, css

Olá,

Como fazer um efeito de escurecer o fundo do site ao passar o mouse sobre o título principal?

Igual deste site:

https://www.santander.com.br/

Já tentei este addClass mas não deu certo :(

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#titulo-banner").mouseover(function(event){
      $("#cor").addClass("escurece");
   });
   $("#titulo-banner").mouseout(function(event){
      $("#cor").removeClass("escurece");
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Talvez o problema esteja no seu css

Comment: Poste seu css também

Answer (score 5):

Pode usar também um pseudo-elemento `::before`. Basta adicionar a classe `.escurece` no contêiner do link onde você quer aplicar o efeito e também adicionar a classe `.m_esc` no elemento alvo do mouse.

O método `.hover()` do jQuery irá adicionar a classe `.ativo` ao contêiner do elemento alvo disparando o `transition` do CSS.

No `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);` o valor `.5` significa metade da transparência. Você pode ajustar esse valor como achar melhor.

E o valor `.5s` em `transition: background-color .5s ease;` significa que o efeito durará meio segundo (500ms). Você pode ajustar também esse valor como achar melhor.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(".m_esc").hover(
   function(){
      $(this)
      .closest(".escurece")
      .addClass("ativo");
   },
   function(){
      $(this)
      .closest(".escurece")
      .removeClass("ativo")
   }
);
```

```css
/* código abaixo apenas exemplo*/
div{
   background-color: blue;
   padding: 20px;
   color: #fff;
}

a{
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 2em;
}
/* código acima apenas exemplo*/


.escurece{
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}

.escurece.ativo::before{
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.escurece::before{
   content: '';
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: -1;
   -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease;
   transition: background-color .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="escurece">
   <a class="m_esc" href="#">Esta div irá ecurecer porque possui a classe .escurece</a>
   <br>
   Texto texto
</div>
<div>
   <a href="#">Esta div NÃO irá ecurecer porque NÃO possui a classe .escurece</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Maravilha, funcionou certinho! 
Eu estava usando o filter:brigthness, mas assim ficou melhor aindal!
Obrigado

Comment: Beleza. Não deixe de qualificar a resposta se lhe atendeu.